# Custom VideoView resize issue

Tags: android, android-videoview

I have Created Custom VideoView. CustomVideoView work good if i give width of Custom VideoView fill parent(match parent).But when i give width of Custom VideoView wrap content then VideoView show with wrap content height.and video does not play. I give height of Videoview 200dp(fix) but it show on more than 200dp. Please give suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You should implement the OnVideoSizeChangedListener and then set the width of your VideoView once invoked:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.OnVideoSizeChangedListener.html